# checking if current time (UTC) falls in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I can currently check this successfully as long as its within the same day however, if the time spans across 2 days it fails.

I need to make it work for multiple days as well.

Any ideas?

** **Update** **

The environment which this will be used in is continuously changing so I don't want to set a fixed date for this.

This is what I have at the moment:

```js
var startTime,
  endTime,
  currentTime = moment.utc(),
  result,
  time,
  str = '';

function test() {

  str += 'Current UTC Time <br>';
  str += currentTime.format() + '<br>';
  str += '------------------------------ <br>';

  startTime = moment.utc('01:00', 'HH:mm');
  endTime = moment.utc('10:00', 'HH:mm');

  result = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  str += 'Test one: ' + result + '<br>';
  str += 'start 01:00 - end 10:00 <br>';
  str += 'result is True which is correct <br>';
  str += '------------------------------ <br>';

  startTime = moment.utc('23:00', 'HH:mm');
  endTime = moment.utc('07:00', 'HH:mm');

  result = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  str += 'Test two: ' + result + '<br>';
  str += 'start 23:00 - end 07:00 <br>';
  str += 'This spans across two days and the result is false which is incorrect <br>';

  $('div').html(str);

}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is for a date range not time

Comment: your start and end time need to contain the date and the time for isBetween to work correctly.

Comment: Awesome, any idea how to integrate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at periods that can be over several days `startTime = moment.utc('23:00', 'HH:mm');` doesn't contain enough information for that purpose.  There's nothing there to say whether 23:00 is tonight, yesterday etc.

Also, your first test passes only if assumed that '01:00' means today at 1am and not yesterday at 1am. If was yesterday at 1am and the current time was 0:15 then it would report false when it should be true.

If you implement a rule to determine whether the time is today or some other day then you can do the following to make your comparison work:

```
  var startPreviousDay = true;
  var endNextDay = true;

  startTime = moment.utc('23:00', 'HH:mm');
  if (startPreviousDay) startTime = startTime.subtract(1, 'day');

  endTime = moment.utc('07:00', 'HH:mm');
  if (endNextDay) endTime = endTime.add(1, 'day');
```

What the rules are to set those depends entirely on what information you have available as to the user's intention.

```js
var startTime,
  endTime,
  currentTime = moment.utc(),
  result,
  time,
  str = '';

function test() {

  str += 'Current UTC Time <br>';
  str += currentTime.format() + '<br>';
  str += '------------------------------ <br>';

  startTime = moment.utc('01:00', 'HH:mm');
  endTime = moment.utc('10:00', 'HH:mm');

  result = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  str += 'Test one: ' + result + '<br>';
  str += 'start 01:00 - end 10:00 <br>';
  str += 'result is True which is correct <br>';
  str += '------------------------------ <br>';

  var startPreviousDay = true;
  var endNextDay = true;
  
  startTime = moment.utc('23:00', 'HH:mm');
  if (startPreviousDay) startTime = startTime.subtract(1, 'day');
  
  endTime = moment.utc('07:00', 'HH:mm');
  if (endNextDay) endTime = endTime.add(1, 'day');

  result = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  str += 'Test two: ' + result + '<br>';
  str += 'start 23:00 - end 07:00 <br>';
  str += 'startPreviousDay = true and endNextDay = true spans across three days so the result will true<br>';

  $('div').html(str);

}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only need this to span two days not three (yesterday and today). Thanks for the help though

Comment: You can set `endNextDay = false` for yesterday and today only (or remove that piece of code)

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a few ways to both get and set your dates with UTC. From what I understand, the format function will parse the input and convert whatever it reads into the desired format, as long as both are valid. This should allow you to test between dates, times, and halves of the day. Not only that, but the input seems pretty flexible as well, and will take in a variety of input types and formats. Hope this helps!

Edit: I'm new to Stack Overflow answers and as such my snippet is long and dumb, sorry

```js
var startTime,
  endTime,
  currentTime = moment.utc(),
  result,
  time,
  str = '';

function test() {
  startTime = moment.utc("2016-11-09 22:00");
  endTime = moment.utc("2016-11-10 10:30");

  str += "startTime " + startTime.format("MM DD hh:mm a");
  str += "<br>";
  str += "endTime " + endTime.format("MM DD hh:mm a");
  str += "<br>";

  result = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  str += 'Test two: ' + result + '<br>';
  startTime = startTime.format("MM DD hh:mm a");
  endTime = endTime.format("MM DD hh:mm a");
  currentTime = currentTime.format("MM DD hh:mm a");

  str += "current time normal : " + currentTime;
  str += "<br>";
  str += "start time normal : " + startTime;
  str += "<br>";
  str += "end time normal : " + endTime;
  str += "<br>";

  $('div').html(str);
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need this in UTC time if it's possible

Comment: The environment which this will be used in is continuously changing so I don't want to set a fixed date for this